# Prevent Elements from Loading with CSS?

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm working on a video carousel in bootstrap, and ran into an issue: many mobile devices can't autoplay HTML5 video. No problem I thought, I'll just use the hidden-desktop and hidden-mobile tags from the CSS, then have the desktop run the mp4 video while the mobile version can use animated gifs.

The issue I ran into is that the animated gifs are /heavy/ (~3+mb gif vs ~100kb mp4). Since I haven't found a workaround for the autoplay issue I decided that I'd have to live with it for now, but I'd like to prevent the desktop version of the site from actually downloading those 20mb of gifs, and this is my question. How to do it?

AFAIK, using class="hidden-desktop" will still download the gifs, but simply hide them. Is there a way to tell the browser to simply ignore the files?

Here's what it looks like on Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/1aasjs23/13/

```
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-interval="19000" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-interval="19000" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-interval="19000" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <!-- Item 1 -->
      <div class="item active">
        <div align="center">
          <div class="hidden-phone">
            <div class="hidden-tablet">
              <video autoplay loop>
                <source src="http://bluelotusvape.com/assets/img/future_short.mp4" type="video/mp4"> Your browser does not support the video tag.
              </video>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="hidden-desktop">
            <img src="http://bluelotusvape.com/assets/img/future_short.gif" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h4>First Thumbnail label</h4>
          <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Item 2 -->
      <div class="item">
        <div align="center">
          <div class="hidden-phone">
            <div class="hidden-tablet">
              <video autoplay loop>
                <source src="http://bluelotusvape.com/assets/img/vape.mp4" type="video/mp4"> Your browser does not support the video tag.
              </video>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="hidden-desktop">
            <img src="http://bluelotusvape.com/assets/img/vape.gif" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h4>Second Thumbnail label</h4>
          <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Item 3 -->
      <div class="item">
        <div align="center">
          <div class="hidden-phone">
            <div class="hidden-tablet">
              <video autoplay loop>
                <source src="http://bluelotusvape.com/assets/img/max.mp4" type="video/mp4"> Your browser does not support the video tag.
              </video>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="hidden-desktop">
            <img src="http://bluelotusvape.com/assets/img/max.gif" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h4>Third Thumbnail label</h4>
          <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
  </div>
```

You'll notice that it displays both the gif and the mp4, but it doesn't do this in a browser.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  We'd love to help, but we need to see some code that you have at least tried so far.

Comment: Thanks, added code and link to Fiddle :)

Answer (score 0):

You can probably perform a simple javascript workaround for desktop something like this using regx tester:

```
    if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|BB|PlayBook|IEMobile|Windows Phone|Kindle|Silk|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) 
    // Show image carousel
    else
    //load video
```

This will load one or the other. If you want the option to load image carousel for desktop provide a link.
You could also either use **jQuery onload** or **jQuery document ready** and wrap it in the event listener respectively

Comment: Thanks, I'm not familiar with jQuery onload or jQuery document ready so I'll have a look at those!